# Spring Boot: How to access set Locale in Service or Repository layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization, locale

I followed some tutorials for internationalization in Spring Boot.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7pHhui0cD4 and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization)

I came so far to configure it like this:

```
@Configuration
public class InternationalizationConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean 
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

and to use it in the RestConroller like this:

```
@RestController
public class ExperimentalControllerImpl implements ExperimentalController{

    @Autowired
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public String testI18n(@RequestHeader("Accept-Language") String locale) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(messageSource.getMessage(Messages.HELLO, null, new Locale(locale)));
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append(messageSource.getMessage(Messages.HOW_ARE_YOU, null, new Locale(locale)));
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

It works fine.....

**But how do I get the locale information from the request header to my service layer or my repository layers?**

Is there a **best practise** to store the information which locale is sent by the request, so that I can access it in my services and repositories? I think the value must be **request/thread specific**. Giving it as a method parameter down to the other layer seems pretty ugly.

Thank you
Regards form Germany

Comment: Why do you _want_ it in your repository layer?  There's `ThreadLocal` and `InheritableThreadLocal` if you just want to pass through to other layers.  But putting it in your repository sounds like a bad idea (_maybe_ the service layer, but even then, I wouldn't).

Comment: I want it in the service or repository layer because I have validations there. And when a vlaidation fails I create an exception with an error message. These error messages should be internationalized. So I need to put the requested locale in the messageSoruce.getMessage()-Method. Why is that a bad idea? Should exception texts not be internationalized?

Comment: Sorry for delay.  I'd avoid this on the premise of keeping business logic apart from my 'user facing' part.  Internationalisation is very much the 'user facing' part.  If it were me, I would have various types of Exceptions internally, but then either catch those in the controller and handle the language there, or handle them with an `@ExceptionHandler` which deals with the language instead.  No need for different messages in the lower layers.

Comment: Just to add a little to _why_ this is usually better practise.  Does your repository/service layer _care_ if they were called from HTTP?  What if you had a `@Scheduled` (or various other invocation scenarios) method, that might want to call the repository to do things?  Would you give it some default `Locale`?  It's only the HTTP specific part that _cares_ that there was a different `Locale` involved.